# Need help getting data from multiple columns based of specific row information in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need help getting data from multiple columns based of specific row information (Blue and Red), then returning different columns for each of the row criteria.

example :

From Table_Colours

```
ID |  Code Type  | Code
1  |  Blue       | Blue1XX
2  |  Red        | Red1XX
2  |  Blue       | Blue1XX
3  |  Red        | Red1XX
4  |  Blue       | Blue1XX
4  |  Red        | Red1XX
5  |  Blue       | Blue1XX
```

I need to return

```
ID | Blue     | Red   
1  | Blue1XX  |        
2  | Blue1XX  | Red1XX
3  |          | Red1XX
4  | Blue1XX  | Red1XX
5  | Blue1XX  |
```

Blue always returns Blue1XX  (6 number code)
Red always returns Red1XX   (5 number code)

I will need to search with a specific string of ID's such as :

```
AND ID IN (
'1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are "Red" And "Blue" the only two values/new columns?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you only have one or no matches for the ID AND specific CodeType.  Also, it assumes MySQL.  If using SQL SERVER, removed `LIMIT 1` AND put `TOP 1` right after each `SELECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
       (SELECT Code FROM MyTable AS T1 
        WHERE T1.ID=T0.ID AND T1.`Code Type`='Blue' LIMIT 1) AS BlueCode,
       (SELECT Code FROM MyTable AS T2 
        WHERE T2.ID=T0.ID AND T2.`Code Type`='Red' LIMIT 1) AS RedCode
FROM MyTable T0
WHERE T0.ID IN ('1','2','3')
ORDER BY T0.ID
```

Comment: Hi, its MYSQL. There will be multiple matches for ID as in the example, 4 appears twice as it has blue and red value yet 3 only appears once (just red value). I cant seem to get it to work. Getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error. Thanks for your help by the way. Appreciated.

Comment: @user1551795, I used `CodeType` instead of `Code Type`.  I changed the answer.  This should work now.  You can play with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/072a7/3/0

Comment: To the OP: you should have said earlier that "it is mysql". I would not have bothered to create a CTE based answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH pair AS (
        WITH red AS (
                SELECT id,  zcode FROM table_colours WHERE code_type = 'Red'
                )
        , blue AS (
                SELECT id,  zcode FROM table_colours WHERE code_type = 'Blue'
                )
        SELECT COALESCE(b.id, r.id) AS id
                , b.zcode AS blue
                , r.zcode AS red
        FROM blue b
        FULL JOIN red r ON r.id = b.id
        )
SELECT * FROM pair
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
        ;
```

Result:

```
 id |  blue   |  red   
----+---------+--------
  1 | Blue1XX | 
  2 | Blue1XX | Red1XX
  4 | Blue1XX | Red1XX
  3 |         | Red1XX
(4 rows)
```

NOTE: the mysql-tag was added later. (mysql does not allow CTE's)

To the OP: you should have said earlier that "it is mysql". I would not have bothered to create a CTE based answer in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select id, code as 'Blue', null as 'Red'
from table
where code_type like 'Blue'

union

select id, null as 'Blue', code as 'Red'
from table
where code_type like 'Red'
```

Comment: It will give the blue and red data in different rows not in different columns.